# Processing each row of a large database table in Python

Tags: python, bigdata, psycopg2

### Context

I have a function in python that scores a row in my table. I would like to combine the scores of all the rows arithmetically (eg. computing the sum, average, etc.. of the scores).

```
def compute_score(row):
  # some complicated python code that would be painful to convert into SQL-equivalent
  return score
```

The obvious first approach is to simply read in all the data

```
import psycopg2

def sum_scores(dbname, tablename):
  conn = psycopg2.connect(dbname)
  cur = conn.cursor()
  cur.execute('SELECT * FROM ?', tablename)
  rows = cur.fetchall()
  sum = 0
  for row in rows:
    sum += score(row)
  conn.close()
  return sum
```

### Problem

I would like to be able to handle as much data as my database can hold. This could be larger that what would fit into Python's memory, so `fetchall()` seems to me like it would not function correctly in that case.

### Proposed Solutions

I was considering 3 approaches, all with the aim of processing a couple records at a time:

1. One-by-one record processing using `fetchone()`

   ```
   def sum_scores(dbname, tablename):
     ...
     sum = 0
     for row_num in cur.rowcount:
       row = cur.fetchone()
       sum += score(row)
     ...
     return sum
   ```
2. Batch-record processing using `fetchmany(n)`

   ```
   def sum_scores(dbname, tablename):
     ...
     batch_size = 1e3 # tunable
     sum = 0
     batch = cur.fetchmany(batch_size)  
     while batch:
       for row in batch:
         sum += score(row)
       batch = cur.fetchmany(batch_size)
     ...
     return sum
   ```
3. Relying on the cursor's iterator

   ```
   def sum_scores(dbname, tablename):
     ...
     sum = 0
     for row in cur:
       sum += score(row)
     ...
     return sum
   ```

### Questions

1. Was my thinking correct in that my 3 proposed solutions would only pull in manageable sized chunks of data at a time? Or do they suffer from the same problem as `fetchall`?
2. Which of the 3 proposed solutions would work (ie. compute the correct score combination and not crash in the process) for LARGE datasets?
3. How does the cursor's iterator (Proposed Solution #3) actually pull in data into Python's memory? One-by-one, in batches, or all at once?

Comment: let the DB do the math. Use [SQL's SUM](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_sum.asp)

Comment: @Pynchia My `compute_score` is written in python. Assuming I can't convert it to an SQL-equivalent, how would I 'let the DB do the math'?

Comment: If your code is querying an SQL DB with psycopg... how can't it let the DB do its job...

Comment: Have you tried the three solutions?

Comment: Can you convert `compute_score` to use `numpy` vectorization?

Comment: @zmbq I haven't tried them since I'm not sure what a good memory-usage benchmark would be. Either way, I wanted to understand the *conceptual* differences (eg. how do these methods move data into Python's memory), not so much the practical pros/cons (eg. which one is the fastest in practice).

Comment: Conceptually, retrieving data in batches is more efficient. Regarding optimal batch size, it depends (among other things) on the record size and your DB restrictions (a database response usually cannot exceed certain size). Usually that limit is much less than  the size of your available memory, by the way.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All 3 solutions will work, and only bring a subset of the results into memory.

Iterating via the cursor, Proposed solution #3, will work the same as Proposed Solution #2, if you pass a name to the cursor. Iterating over the cursor will fetch *itersize* records (default is 2000).

Solutions #2 and #3 will be much quicker than #1, because there is much less of a connection overhead.

http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/cursor.html#fetch

Comment: @PedroCattori your repo is gone?  Could you restore it, or update the link?